# Less than comparison for date in spark scala rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, bigdata

I want to print data of employees who joined before 1991. Below is my sample data:

```
69062,FRANK,ANALYST,5646,1991-12-03,3100.00,,2001
63679,SANDRINE,CLERK,69062,1990-12-18,900.00,,2001
```

Initial RDD for loading data:

```
val rdd=sc.textFile("file:////home/hduser/Desktop/Employees/employees.txt").filter(p=>{p!=null && p.trim.length>0})
```

UDF for converting string column to date column:

```
def convertStringToDate(s: String): Date = {
        val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
        dateFormat.parse(s)
    }
```

Mapping each and every column to its datatype:

```
val dateRdd=rdd.map(_.split(",")).map(p=>(if(p(0).length >0 )p(0).toLong else 0L,p(1),p(2),if(p(3).length > 0)p(3).toLong else 0L,convertStringToDate(p(4)),if(p(5).length >0)p(5).toDouble else 0D,if(p(6).length > 0)p(6).toDouble else 0D,if(p(7).length> 0)p(7).toInt else 0))
```

Now I get data in tuples as below:

```
(69062,FRANK,ANALYST,5646,Tue Dec 03 00:00:00 IST 1991,3100.0,0.0,2001)
(63679,SANDRINE,CLERK,69062,Tue Dec 18 00:00:00 IST 1990,900.0,0.0,2001)
```

Now when I execute command I am getting below error:

```
scala> dateRdd.map(p=>(!(p._5.before("1991")))).foreach(println)
<console>:36: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String("1991")
 required: java.util.Date
              dateRdd.map(p=>(!(p._5.before("1991")))).foreach(println)

                                        ^
```

So where am I going wrong ???

Comment: In the Tuples output I think you are supposed to get the date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd" and not in this "Tue Dec 03 00:00:00 IST 1991"  format.

Comment: yes but i dont know why somebody is marking my every post as negative. could you please upvote to 0 pls and the answer to your question is yes but I dont know why am i getting in this format. can you please suggest some thing

Comment: Sure, I will post the answer shortly once I test in my local. For the downvote, I would suggest reaching out to the stack overflow team.

Comment: Anyone on this ??

Comment: I dont know why but it is giving error on simpledateformat. I imported java.util.Date. still

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working with rdd's and no df's and you have date strings with simple date checking, the following non-complicated way for an RDD:

```
val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq((69062,"FRANK","ANALYST",5646, "1991-12-03",3100.00,2001),(63679,"SANDRINE","CLERK",69062,"1990-12-18",900.00,2001)))
rdd.filter(p=>(p._5 < "1991-01-01")).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Okay thanks. will check it out . starting my VM. Meanwhil can you check this post as well . Its related to sqoop https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52641463/sqoop-merge-key-creating-multiple-part-files-instead-of-one-which-doesnt-serve

Comment: Yeah this worked. Thank you again for suggesting such a simple solution. It would help me from certification perspective. Can you look into the other problem of mine which I posted above??

Comment: No issues . Whenever you get time , please look into it

Comment: I have had edited this answer. Please review and accept it

Comment: Not sure what you mean here.

Comment: I have edited the code which worked in my machine, sir. So please review and accept it which will help other peeps as well. Thanks :)

Comment: There is no need to edit my answer. There may be more than 1 way of doing something. That is not an error.

Comment: Okay . Have u figured out some solution for my sqoop mergekey problem ??

Comment: can you look at my new problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677045/understanding-of-combinebykey

Answer (score 0):

No need to convert the date to legacy SimpleDate formats. Use Java.time. Since the 4th column is in the ISO expected format, you can simply use the below rdd step.
Check this out

```
val rdd=spark.sparkContext.textFile("in\\employees.txt").filter( x => {val y = x.split(","); java.time.LocalDate.parse(y(4)).isBefore(java.time.LocalDate.parse("1991-01-01")) } )
```

the

```
rdd.collect.foreach(println)
```

gave the below result

```
63679,SANDRINE,CLERK,69062,1990-12-18,900.00,,2001
```

hope, this answers your question.

**EDIT1:**

Using Java 7 and SimpleFormat libraries

```
import java.util.Date
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
object DTCheck{
  def main(args:Array[String]): Unit = {

    def convertStringToDate(s: String): Date = {
      val dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
      dateFormat.parse(s)
    }
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("Employee < 1991").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()

    val  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")
    val dt_1991 = sdf.parse("1991-01-01")

    import spark.implicits._
    val rdd=spark.sparkContext.textFile("in\\employees.txt").filter( x => {val y = x.split(","); convertStringToDate(y(4)).before(dt_1991 ) } )
    rdd.collect.foreach(println)
  }
}
```

Comment: Will try it out and let u know

Comment: I tried it throws this error <console>:29: error: object time is not a member of package java

Comment: This is my code              val rdd=sc.textFile("file:///home/cloudera/Desktop/Employees/employees.txt").filter( x => {val y = x.split(","); java.time.LocalDate.parse(y(4)).isBefore(java.time.LocalDate.parse("1991-01-01")) } )

Comment: Are you not using Java 8

Comment: Nope. It's java 7 with spark 1.6 in cdh

Comment: Anyone on this ??

Comment: Okay np bro. Thank you for your efforts :)

Comment: check my EDIT1  for Java 7. I reused your UDF and it gave the same output.

Comment: Okay I'll try it and will let u know